# is $\omega$ in every model of ZFC always isomorphic to the standard natural numbers

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

ZFC can have some very odd models one of them being countable. Is it true that in any model of ZFC  $\omega$ with the empty set as zero the successor function $S(x):= x\cup\{x\}$ and the addition and moltiplication functions defined by recursion is isomorphic to the "real" natural numbers. I know that Second order arithmetic with quantifiers over all the subsets of it's domain is categorical but from my understanding in some ZFC models not all of the subsets of $\omega$ are sets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No (assuming ZFC is consistent).  This is essentially immediate from the compactness theorem.  For instance, add uncountably many constant symbols $c_i$ to the language of ZFC, and add axioms saying that $c_i\neq c_j$ for each $i\neq j$ and $c_i\in\omega$ for each $i$.  Every finite subset of the resulting theory is consistent, since it will only involve finitely many of the $c_i$ and so we can send those $c_i$ to distinct natural numbers in some model of ZFC and the rest to $0$.  So by compactness, this theory has a model $M$.  Then $M$ is a model of ZFC such that $\omega^M$ has (externally) uncountably many elements.

Comment: A "gentler" use of compactness, leading to a weaker conclusion still sufficient to answer the question: Adjoin just one constant $c$ to the language, and add axioms saying $c\in\omega$, $c\neq0$, $c\neq 1$, $c\neq 2$, etc.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Sorry, but how do you state "$c\neq 0$, $c\neq 1$, $c\neq 2$, etc."? What is $\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ here?

Comment: @AndreasBlass Ah I see, we get a model $M'$ of ZFC whose "set of natural numbers" $\omega'$ satisfies: there exists $c\in\omega'$ such that $c\neq {s'}^{(n)}(0)$ for all $n\in\omega$, where ${s'}^{(0)}=0$, ${s'}^{s(n)}(0)=s'({s'}^{(n)}(0))$ for $n\in\omega$, $\omega$ is the set of natural numbers in our original model, $s$ and $s'$ are the successor function in $\omega$ and $\omega'$ respectively.